# Struggling to define a polymorphic relationship which includes a BelongsTo

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I'm working on a text-based, rng-based motorsport "simulator" and I'm now at the point where I want to add qualifying. Since there's many different types of qualifying sessions across real life motorsport, I want to give the user the ability to use whatever format they like.

I have a `Season` model, to which the a qualifying format will belong. The different formats are defined as separate models themselves, for example `ThreeSessionElimination` and `SingleSession`. The migrations for these would look something like this;

```
Schema::create('three_session_eliminations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignId('season_id')->constrained();
    $table->unsignedInteger('q2_driver_count');
    $table->unsignedInteger('q3_driver_count');
    $table->unsignedInteger('runs_per_session');
    $table->unsignedInteger('min_rng');
    $table->unsignedInteger('max_rng');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('single_sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignId('season_id')->constrained();
    $table->unsignedInteger('runs_per_session');
    $table->unsignedInteger('min_rng');
    $table->unsignedInteger('max_rng');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My initial thought was to add

```
public function season(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Season::class);
}
```

to each qualifying format model, but obviously the inverse can't be a `HasOne` since there's different tables for each different format.

I've had a look at the ["One To Many (Polymorphic)" relation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations), but I can't quite wrap my head around how I should apply that in my case. Would I have to add a `qualifying_format_id` and `qualifying_format_type` to my `Season` model and remove the `season_id` column from each format migration to make this work?

Comment: unless I'm mistaken I don't think you need polymorphism here, since a qualifying format will always belong to a season and a season may have one or more qualifying formats, it makes more sense for a one-to-many relationship. Polymorphism is more useful when you want a model to have a relationship that can be of different shapes.

Comment: I must've explained my case incorrectly then, since a season can only have one qualifying format but they're all defined in different models/database tables. I ended up solving it using a polymorphic relation by adding the `format_id` and `format_type` columns on the `Season` table and adding `morphTo('format')` on the `Season` model, and then on each qualifying format model I've added `morphMany(Season::class, 'format')` . This way by calling `Season::qualifyingFormat()` I can retrieve whatever qualifying format is selected.